# How to use an int variable more than once (HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

My program is meant to calculate amount of credits a student has and if they are "University Entrance" (UE) credits.

Once the student enters amount of credits for five subjects I want to calculate the total amount of credits and also the total amount of UE credits, but can't use the assigned amount per standard more than once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dog(curetn){
        var txtJscredit = document.getElementById("txtcredit");
        var txtJscredit2 = document.getElementById("txtcredit2");
        var txtJscredit3 = document.getElementById("txtcredit3");
        var txtJscredit4 = document.getElementById("txtcredit4");
        var txtJscredit5 = document.getElementById("txtcredit5");
        var txtJscredit9 = document.getElementById("txtcredit9");
        if (curetn.includes("credit5")){
            txtcredit9.value = ((parseInt(txtJscredit.value)) + (parseInt(txtJscredit2.value)) + (parseInt(txtJscredit3.value))+ (parseInt(txtJscredit4.value))+ (parseInt(txtJscredit5.value)));
        }
        function myfuntionUE() {
            var checkBox = document.getElementById("Uni");
            var txtJscreditUE = document.getElementById("txtcredit");
            txtcreditUE.value = ((parseInt(txtJscreditUE.value))
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: when you say "you cant" do you mean you're not able to? or you're not allowed to by some constraint you or someone else has placed on your code? because the code is vague at best, cant' see how/when you're calling either function nor what `txtcreditUE` is

Comment: It just doesnt use it in function. creditUE is an output to be displayed aswell as credit9

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var txtJscredit = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit"));
var txtJscredit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit2"));
var txtJscredit3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit3"));
var txtJscredit4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit4"));
var txtJscredit5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit5"));
var txtJscredit9 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit9"));
    function dog(curetn){
if (curetn.includes("credit5")){
    txtcredit9.value = (txtJscredit.value) + (parseInt(txtJscredit2.value)) + (parseInt(txtJscredit3.value))+ (parseInt(txtJscredit4.value))+ (parseInt(txtJscredit5.value)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var txtJscredit;
var txtJscredit2;
var txtJscredit3;
var txtJscredit4;
var txtJscredit5;
var txtJscredit9;
    function dog(curetn){
txtJscredit = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit"));
txtJscredit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit2"));
txtJscredit3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit3"));
txtJscredit4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit4"));
txtJscredit5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit5"));
txtJscredit9 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit9"));
}
```

Comment: Its either not running still or i have done something else wrong because now its not even displaying in the first box.

Comment: How would you then use them in an equation?

Answer (score -2):

You can use some like that:

```
var txtJscredit = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtcredit"));
```

This variable with assume the value of an int.

But take care with this conditions:
https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: Hi thanks for feedback, i understand how to use it as an int just wondering how to use the same input more than once.?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I still dont understande your question. You can use the variable as a input after execute that code: var txtJscredit = document.getElementById("txtcredit");

Comment: YOu dont need to get by id the same input twice.

Comment: Its okie dont be sorry, Its just i cant use that declared variable in two seperate equations

Comment: You can declare the variable out of the function, and than use the same variable in two equations. Is that your question?

Comment: yeah... but it didnt seem to let me do that

Comment: Let me see your code with the var declaration out of the function?